# Yii2 session destroy and redirect to another page is not working properly

Tags: php, redirect, yii2

When I  destroy session and redirect to  page which is related user status, it's redirected, but every time redirecting to home page

In my LoginForm model:

```
 public  function afterLogin(){

            $this->wrong_pass= 0;
            $this->save();
            if(!isset($this->info)){
                Yii::$app->session->destroy();
                Yii::$app->controller->redirect("hr/notfoundpersonal",302);
            }
        }
```

In my behaviors i set these rules:

```
[
   'allow' => true,
   'actions' => ['login','notfoundpersonal'],
  'roles' => ['?'],
],                  
[
   'allow' => true,
   'actions' => ['logout'],
   'roles' => ['@'],
],
```

Any suggestion will be helpful,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the session destroy delete all the user stored reference based on the session iself and thne the framework cand only drive to the home / default page  for accessing operation

Could be you shuold change the default redirection page.

but remember to use

```
return $this->redirect('hr/notfoundpersonal',302);
```

for correct redirection

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge I tried this before, but not help, it's throw exception raised too many redirects. What do you think maybe i should check user status beforeAction in controller instead of  in loginform model. ? So i'm checking now.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to the fact you are in login form. But what is your goals, because you need this behavior?

Comment: My goal is checking user and hr mangement related user fields  usermodel(person_id)<->person(id). and if not found user related person from persons table redirect to notsetperson action. I tried this staff from afterlogining to system beforeAction() method. Callback return actionNotsetperson() method it is rendered view file . But now it is redirecting after a little time

Comment: But why you destroy the session?

Comment: what do prefer to use for this situation (for logout user when not found person for security reasons)

Comment: Why not simply logout ? and then redirect to notfoundpersonale page

Comment: I did this : Yii::$app->user->logout(); $this->redirect("hr/notfoundpersonal",302);   But this time i got exception too many redirects to hr/notfoundpersonal  page.

Comment: I have update teh answer you should use` return $this->redirect('hr/notfoundpersonal',302);`

Answer (score 1):

You should put the url in brackets to transform it to an absolute:

```
Yii::$app->controller->redirect(["hr/notfoundpersonal"],302);
```

Info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#redirect%28%29-detail

Comment: Thanks @stig-js but this is not helped to me